# Read Midi File using Unity3D on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, midi

I am developing a Unity3D app to be deployed on Android.
I need to read midi files (preferrably as .midi, but other endings would be fine too) and play them (get the parsed note events at the correct timing).
Actual sound is not a priority.

It is also very important for me to be able to change the tempo.

Can you recommend a framework/ plugin/ code for this?

All the stuff i found does not work on Android, regarding C#SynthProject i could not figure out how to change the tempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the sound is somewhat problematic (as you have noticed) as you need to emulate hardware chip that used to do the GeneralMIDI synthesis in some form or another, that is no longer commonly mounted anywhere (even windows emulates this internally), but midi file format (also known as StandardMidiFile aka SMF) files themselves are fairly well documented standard and are not terribly complex (although two non-compatible variants are a pain sometimes)

While writing own .MID file parser is probably a lot of fun, I can recommend using this piece of code dated 2013, written by our Unity god - Keijiro Takahashi

https://github.com/keijiro/smflite

Comment: it's a nice piece of code, but it only gets midi events as their byte codes. I'm looking for events with note code etc so i will probably go for a more complex library

Comment: the bytecode to note conversion is trivial - there's no conversion actually, just interpretation (each midi note is 3 bytes and their structure is very very simple by deisgn)

Comment: For what i've read so far, it's a bit more complex. Afaik stuff like endianness needs to be regarded and i'm afraid i'll lose a lot of time if i look into all of this. I'd rather steal someone else's working code

Comment: I actually got it working easily after really looking into it for once.
It should be noted though that Keijiro's parser only processes NoteOn and NoteOff events.

Comment: there's very little difference between NoteOn/Off and CCs's (one bit of difference actually), while its somethimes hard to match Keijiro's style, hacking something on top of it should not be too hard. What other types of events do you need?